# How to use R AWS packages in Single Sign-On environment

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have searched online but I cannot find a way to use the packages such as aws.translate. My company accesses AWS using SSO and we cannot generate key pairs. I launched an ec2 instance where I run a docker file which contains R and Python. I believe lots of corporate users face similar issues. Could someone please guild on how to use those CloudyR packages in SSO environment?

I installed aws.translate, aws.ec2metadata and aws.signature. use_credentials cannot find .aws/credentials file. ecs.metadata() returns NULL. And I receive Bad Request HTTP 400 if I directly use the translate function.

Comment: turns out that I can ask our cloud dev-ops to create an IAM role and attach to my EC2 instance for me to use the API